# Adding conditional to column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this script and I'm trying to add a if statement if column GTIN is empty then column excluded_destination should be FALSE else TRUE. I'm not sure how to check the GTIN Column.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

ed = pd.read_csv('/export.csv')
df = ed[['ItemID', 'ProductUrl', 'RetailPrice', 'ItemName', 'ItemName', 'ItemPrimaryImageUrl'
        , 'CategoryList', 'Manufacturer', 'GTIN', 'ProductStatus','CategoryList', 'ItemNumber']]

def build_csv():
        df.insert(0, 'expiration_date', '2020-12-24')
        df.insert(7, 'additional_image_link', ' ')
        df.insert(9, 'condition', 'new')
        df.insert(10, 'shipping_weight', '0.0000 lb')
        df.insert(12, 'pattern', ' ')
        df.insert(16, 'tax', 'US::0:n')
        df.insert(17, 'promotion_id', '')
        df.insert(18, 'color', '')
        df.insert(19, 'size', '')
        df.insert(20, 'shipping', ':::0.00')
        df.insert(22, 'item_group_id', ' ')
        df.insert(23, 'adwords_grouping', ' ')
        df.insert(24, 'adword_labels', ' ')
        df.insert(25, 'custom_label_0', ' ')
        df.insert(26, 'custom_label_1', ' ')
        df.insert(27, 'custom_label_2', ' ')
        df.insert(28, 'custom_label_3', ' ')
        df.insert(29, 'shipping_label', '1')
        df.insert(30, 'excluded_destination', ' ')
        if df['GTIN'] != ' ':
            df.insert(31, 'identifier_exists', 'TRUE')
        else:
            df.insert(31, 'identifier_exists', 'FALSE')

        df.columns =['expiration_date','id', 'link', 'price', 'title', 'description','image_link', 'additional_image_link'
                , 'product_type', 'condition', 'shipping_weight','brand', 'pattern', 'gtin', 'availability', 'google_product_category'
                ,'tax', 'promotion_id', 'color', 'size','shipping','mpn', 'item_group_id', 'adwords_grouping', 'adword_labels'
                , 'custom_label_0', 'custom_label_1', 'custom_label_2', 'custom_label_3', 'shipping_label', 'excluded_destination'
                , 'identifier_exists'] 
                
        df.to_csv('/home/d_google_file.csv')

build_csv()
```

Comment: Since you are resetting the df.columns anyway just before you write to csv file, you don't need to do insert statements. Instead, you can just do simple `df['expiration_date'] = '2020-12-24'` and so on. The df.columns statement will reset the columns in the order you have defined.

Comment: You can also give something like this: `df[['Test1','Test2']] = ['A','B']`. In this case, `Test1` will be assigned with value `A` and `Test2` will be assigned with value `B`. That way, you can create a list of columns and a list of values. Then do a single assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> column excluded_destination should be FALSE else TRUE

Not sure if you meant `identifier_exists` or `excluded_destination`, because your code seems to suggest the former.

If you want `identifier_exists` to change based on the value of `GTIN`, you can simply do:

```
df['identifier_exists'] = df['GTIN'] == ""
```

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [2, 3, ""],
    [2, 3, "hello"],
    [1, 5, ""]
], columns=['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'])

    Test1   Test2   Test3
0   2       3   
1   2       3       hello
2   1       5   

df1['hello'] = df1['Test3'] == ""

    Test1   Test2   Test3   hello
0   2       3               True
1   2       3       hello   False
2   1       5               True
```

This can be done after your last insert statement (before `df.columns`).

In your code, `df.insert(...)` inserts an *entire* column with the specified value. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html).

Comment: This seems to change them all to True or False but I want it to be on a row by row basis so if row 1 GTIN column is empty then column identifier_exists gets False added to it and if the next row has data in the gtin column I want identifier_exists to have TRUE added to it.

Comment: Seems like using `df.insert` doesn't help your use case. Edited my answer.

Comment: The df.insert are used to help maintain a certain order the file needs to be in. Im only pulling certain columns from the export file but the new file needs to have all these additional columns so using the insert allows me set them in the order I need I tried df['identifier_exists'] = df['GTIN'] == "" but it just marked all the cells under the identifier_exists column as false, if a row has data in the gtin cell then the idetifier cell should be marked as TRUE, if there is no datra it should get a false, this needs to be done row by row,

Comment: That's strange; using `df['identifier_exists'] = df['GTIN'] == ""` should work; see example. Can you check to see if there are indeed non-empty/empty strings in the `identifier_exists` column?

Comment: In your example I would actually be trying to get the hello columns results flipped.. The first row should be False because the actual question is does column GTIN contain data if yes then TRUE if not then FALSE also I need the All Caps version of TRUE and FALSE either way the code you tried still just returns all false for every row in the column, I checked the GTIN column and there should be many cells with and without data in the GTIN so the results under identifier_exists Column should reflect that. The cells without GTIN are empty but is that the same as being = ''?

Comment: You can try `== " "` instead? There might be an empty space inside

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. Note that you don't need if else statement for this. The condition itself is part of the statement.

```
df.loc[(df['GTIN'] == ' '), 'identifier_exists'] = True
df.loc[~(df['GTIN'] == ' '), 'identifier_exists'] = False
```

It is checking if `df['GTIN']` is space. If yes, then a new column `'identifier_exists'` will be assigned a value of `True`

The tilda `~` does the negative of that.

If you were not redefining the column order later and you want to maintain the column position, then you can give this statement before the above two statements.

```
df.insert(31, 'identifier_exists', '')
```

Also, as you are redefining the column order later in the code using `df.columns = [......`, you can do a simple assignment.

```
    df['expiration_date'] = '2020-12-24'
    df['additional_image_link'] = ' '
    df['condition'] = 'new'
    df['shipping_weight'] = '0.0000 lb'
```

etc...

Comment: I get this error with this code: raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
Im trying to change this row my row so if row 1 gtin is empty the identifier column gets false and if it has a gtin the identifier column gets true

Comment: can you share the contents of `df['GTIN']`. Maybe it has more than one space. Are you sure it has a space and not `''` ? To get the contents of `GTIN`, you can give `df['GTIN'].to_list()`

Comment: im checking for a empty cell so if that rows gtin columns cell is empty(no data) then the identifier column cell gets FALSE written to it

Comment: Note that a value of `''` is not the same as Null.